# Use epsilon-delta definition of limits to show that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,2)}(x^2+3x-4y)=-4$ and $\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,-1)}(x^2+y^2)=2$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Use epsilon-delta definition of limits to show that

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,2)}(x^2+3x-4y)=-4$$
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,-1)}(x^2+y^2)=2$$

We need to show that $$\forall \epsilon >0( \exists \delta >0( \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 (0<\sqrt{\left(x-1\right)^{2}+\left(y-2\right)^{2}}<\delta \implies \left|\left(x^2+3x-4y\right)+4\right|<\epsilon)))$$

Taking $\left|x-1\right|,\left|y-2\right|<\delta$ follows :
$$\left|\left(x^2+3x-4y\right)+4\right|\le \left|x+4\right|\left|x-1\right|+4\left|y-2\right|< (\delta+5)\left|x-1\right|+4\left|y-2\right|$$

Let $ \delta \le 1$:

$$\left|\left(x^2+3x-4y\right)+4\right|< 6\left|x-1\right|+4\left|y-2\right|$$

So taking $\delta \le \epsilon/10$ proves the claim.

---

We need to show that $$\forall \epsilon >0( \exists \delta >0( \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 (0<\sqrt{\left(x-1\right)^{2}+\left(y+1\right)^{2}}<\delta \implies \left|\left(x^2+y^2\right)-2\right|<\epsilon)))$$

$$\left|\left(x^2+y^2\right)-2\right| \le \left|x-1\right|\left|x+1\right| +\left|y-1\right|\left|y+1\right|$$

Taking $\left|x-1\right|,\left|y+1\right|<\delta$ and $\delta \le 1$ follows:
$$\left|\left(x^2+y^2\right)-2\right| <3\delta +2\delta$$

So we only need to choose $\delta \le \epsilon/5$.

I want to know if my solution is true,so if you have an alternative solution that would be nice to see that,but please **first** check mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems okay; the way you take $\delta$ is not very clear.

I would write the first one as follows. (Similarly for the second one.)

---

Let $\epsilon>0$. The estimate
$$
\begin{align}
|x^2+3x-4y-(-4)|
&=|x^2+3x-4y-(1^2+3\cdot 1-4\cdot 2)|\\
&\le |x+1|\cdot |x-1|+3|x-1|+4|y-2|\\
&=|x-1+2|\cdot |x-1|+3|x-1|+4|y-2|
\end{align}
$$
suggests that if you take
$$\sqrt{|x-1|^2+|y-2|^2}<\delta\tag{1}$$ then $|x-1|<\delta$ and $|y-1|<\delta$ and thus
$$
|x^2+3x-4y-(-4)|\le (\delta+2)\delta+3\delta+4\delta=(\delta+9)\delta\tag{2}
$$
So if you take $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon/10)$, then (1) implies
$$
|x^2+3x-4y-(-4)|\le (\delta+2)\delta+3\delta+4\delta=(\delta+9)\delta \le 10\delta
\le\epsilon.
$$

Comment: @masaheb: yes. I would say so.

Comment: @masaheb: thanks.